# CommandException: "mb" command does not support "file://" URLs. Did you mean to use a gs:// URL?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, buckets

I am running Google Cloud Shell on my Windows 7, when trying to fire a new bucket on my **PRJOECT** I am getting an error.

> Command --> C:\Users********>gsutil mb gs://**MY-PROJECT-ID** -p
>   **MY-PROJECT-ID**

Error

> CommandException: "mb" command does not support "file://" URLs. Did
>   you mean to use a gs:// URL?

Anyone to help?

thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this (bucket name argument at the end):

```
gsutil mb -p my-project-id gs://my-bucket-name
```

Answer (score 7):

set cloud platform with the current project before you do anything else

`gcloud config set project qwiklabs-gcp-PROJECT_ID`

Answer (score 0):

I used gs:// before the bucket name and that worked.

```
gsutil mb gs://this-is-also-a-bucket-name-23432
```

I did set the current project with as adviced above

```
gcloud config set project qwiklabs-gcp-PROJECT_ID
```